# Aurelia Validation not working with object properties

Tags: aurelia

I can't get Aurelia-Validate to work on the fields in my calendar record.

**calendar.html** (excerpt)

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="cal_name_orig">Calendar name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cal_name_orig" value.bind="calendar.cal_name_orig & validate">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="cal_name_tran">Translated name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cal_name_tran" value.bind="calendar.cal_name_tran & validate">
  </div>
</form>
```

**calendars.js** (simplified):

```
import { inject, NewInstance } from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import { ValidationController, ValidationRules } from 'aurelia-validation';
import { BootstrapFormRenderer } from '../../common/bootstrap-form-renderer';

@inject(NewInstance.of(ValidationController))
export class CalendarForm {
  controller = null;

  constructor(controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
    this.controller.addRenderer(new BootstrapFormRenderer());
    this.calendar = {
      cal_name_orig = "",
      cal_name_tran = ""
    }
  }

  validateCalendar() {
    let v = this.controller.validate();
    console.log(v);
  }

}

ValidationRules
  .ensure('calendar.cal_name_orig').required().minLength(5).maxLength(20)
  .ensure('calendar.cal_name_tran').minLength(5).maxLength(20)
  .on(CalendarForm);
```

If I change `value.bind="calendar.cal_name_orig & validate"` to `value.bind="cal_name_orig & validate"` and `.ensure('calendar.cal_name_orig')` to `.ensure('cal_name_orig')`, the validation works and renders on the form (but the data doesn't bind to the right part of the data in this class.

*How can I get Aurelia Validate to recognize calendar.cal_name_orig?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to move ValidationRules into the class `constructor()` and change the last line to `on(this.calendar)`.  I also needed to remove the `calendar.` from each of the ensure rules.

```
ValidationRules
  .ensure('cal_name_orig').required().minLength(5).maxLength(20)
  .ensure('cal_name_tran').required().minLength(5).maxLength(20)
  .on(this.calendar);
```

Comment: How could you reference the calendar (an instance variable) in the constructor?

Comment: Should have said in the `attached()` or `activate()` built-in methods.  It would only be possible to reference it from the constructor if it was also set from the constructor.