# Aurelia Validation Gives Error: TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object

Tags: javascript, validation, aurelia

I am trying to do basic Aurelia validation on an Aurelia component, but am getting an error.

The Typescript is:

```
import { bindable, inject, NewInstance } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { HttpClient } from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import { validationMessages, ValidationRules, ValidationController } from 'aurelia-validation';

@inject(HttpClient, NewInstance.of(ValidationController))
export class PersonDetail {
    @bindable currentPerson: Person;
    private httpClient: HttpClient;
    public controller: ValidationController;

    constructor(http: HttpClient, controller: ValidationController) {
        this.httpClient = http;

        this.controller = controller;
        validationMessages['lastNameReq'] = 'You must enter a last name';
        ValidationRules.ensure('LastName').minLength(3).required().withMessageKey('lastNameReq').on(this.currentPerson);

    }

    saveToDb() {
        this.controller.validate()
            .then(v => {
                if (v.valid) {

                    // this.httpClient...(do stuff)
                }
             }
        }
}
```

The html is:

```
<template bindable="currentPerson">

    <form submit.delegate="saveToDb()">
        <p>First Name: <input type="text" class="form-control" value.bind="currentPerson.FirstName"></p>
        <p>Last Name: <input type="text" class="form-control" value.bind="currentPerson.LastName & validate"></p>
        <p>Middle Name: <input type="text" class="form-control" value.bind="currentPerson.MiddleName"></p>
        <p>Gender: <input type="text" class="form-control" value.bind="currentPerson.Sex"></p>
        <p>DOB: <input type="text" class="form-control" value.bind="person.DOB"></p>
        <p>Mobile Phone: <input type="text" class="form-control" value.bind="currentPerson.MobilePhnNbr"></p>
        <p>Email: <input type="text" class="form-control" value.bind="currentPerson.EmailAddr"></p>

        <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Save to Database</button>
        <ul if.bind="controller.errors">
            <li repeat.for="error of controller.errors">
                ${error.message}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</template>
```

Running this I get the following error:

> aurelia-logging-console.js:47 ERROR [app-router] TypeError:
>   Object.defineProperty called on non-object
>       at Function.defineProperty ()
>       at Function.29.Rules.set (rules.js:14)
>       at FluentEnsure.48.FluentEnsure.on (validation-rules.js:347)
>       at FluentRuleCustomizer.48.FluentRuleCustomizer.on (validation-rules.js:95)
>       at PersonDetail.app/components/people/person-detail.PersonDetail.bind
>   (person-detail.ts:27)
>       at View.bind (aurelia-templating.js:1400)
>       at Controller.bind (aurelia-templating.js:3394)
>       at View.bind (aurelia-templating.js:1406)
>       at Controller.bind (aurelia-templating.js:3394)
>       at Controller.automate (aurelia-templating.js:3339)

If I change the ValidationRules line to:

`ValidationRules.ensure('currentPerson.LastName').minLength(3).required().withMessageKey('lastNameReq').on(this);`

then I no longer get the error, but the validation does not work either (this.controller.validate() returns valid when I blank out the last name field). This tallies with what LStarky found here: [Aurelia Validation not working with object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40250698/aurelia-validation-not-working-with-object-properties). However if I implement his solution I get the above error.

Comment: is the `this.curentPerson` property undefined when `ValidationRules.ensure` line runs? I could be wrong, purely guessing based on the error.

Comment: Hi @adiga yes that's correct it was undefined. I came up with a solution below.

Comment: Have you tried applying `ValidationRules` on `Person` class itself, instead of each instance of that class? like this:

`ValidationRules.ensure('LastName').minLength(3).required().withMessageKey('lastNameReq').on(Person)`

Comment: I tried that but got a typescript error TS2693: 'Person' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. Aurelia documentation says you should be able to do that though.

Comment: Okay - managed to get rid of that error by making Person and exported class rather than an Interface and importing it into the ts file. However then the validation didn't work! :-/

Comment: ah, this is why i prefix interfaces with "I" :). 

I add the ValidationRules in the Person.ts itself and it works fine for me. 

Person.ts: 
`export class Person { 
// class code
}

ValidationRules.ensure("property").required().on(Person)`

Comment: I tried that and don't get an error, but the validation still doesn't work. I am importing the Person with: import { Person } from '../../model/person'; I'm wondering if it doesn't run my ValidationRules statement because it's outside the class definition. But that's just a guess.

Comment: in my case i initiate a child class like `currentPerson = new Person(controller)` inside the constructor of `PersonDetail` class. So same instance of controller gets passed and it somehow works fine. Not sure how this would work with @bindabe.

Comment: `.on()` usually requires an object, e.g. `.on(currentPerson)`. But you'll still get the same error if currentPerson is null at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above view/view model pair was being used as a custom element within a page - it was the detail section of a master detail window. This meant that the currentPerson property was undefined when the page and custom element were first created, so I got an error when creating a validation rule on that property.

Also, because the currentPerson changes each time you change the row in the master list, I found I had to create the validation rule every time this happened.

So the solution was to make currentPerson observable and set up the validation rule in the currentPersonChanged method. The final code was as follows:

```
import { bindable, inject, NewInstance, observable } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { HttpClient } from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import { validationMessages, ValidationRules, ValidationController } from 'aurelia-validation';

@inject(HttpClient, NewInstance.of(ValidationController))
export class PersonDetail {
    @bindable @observable currentPerson: Person;
    private httpClient: HttpClient;
    public controller: ValidationController;

    constructor(http: HttpClient, controller: ValidationController) {
        this.httpClient = http;

        this.controller = controller;
        validationMessages['lastNameReq'] = 'You must enter a last name';    
    }

    currentPersonChanged() {
        if (this.currentPerson) {
            ValidationRules.ensure('LastName').minLength(3).required().withMessageKey('lastNameReq').on(this.currentPerson);
        }
    }

    saveToDb() {
        this.controller.validate()
            .then(v => {
                if (v.valid) {

                    // this.httpClient...(do stuff)
                }
             }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically you setup your validation rules in the `bind()` method, especially if the object you're validating - `this.currentPerson` - is `@bindable`, because it's not going to have a value at the time the constructor is called.

```
constructor(http: HttpClient, controller: ValidationController) {
    this.httpClient = http;

    this.controller = controller;
    validationMessages['lastNameReq'] = 'You must enter a last name';
}

bind() {
    ValidationRules.ensure('LastName').minLength(3).required().withMessageKey('lastNameReq').on(this.currentPerson);
}
```

---

Based on your comment, it looks like you don't set the current person when the parent/container loads the element. There are a few ways around this:

1. You can use an `if` binding which will only create the person custom element (detail section) when it has a person attached. (in the parent: `<person-detail if.bind="currentPerson"><person-detail>`). `if` bindings actually add/remove the element into the DOM at the time the result is true, so the view model would only be instantiated and bound when the person object has a value
2. You can watch the bound person object inside the `PersonDetail` class and only call validation rules once it has a non-null value. This is a little more tricky as you should only setup the validation rules once, but it's sometimes the way to go. Use the function called `currentPersonChanged(newVal, oldVal)` and it will automatically get called for you.

If that doesn't work, let me know!

Comment: Hi there. Sorry I should have mentioned I tried it in the bind event as well, but I still get the same error. In this method this.currentPerson is still undefined. I agree that you'd expect it to have a value at this point. The above component is used as the detail section of a master/detail page and the currentPerson is set when you select a record in the master section. I think the problem is related to this set up. I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: oh I see you already found solution #2! I would try #1 if you can as it's a better way of doing it.

Comment: #1 is a good suggestion, but I think the best way would be to just put validation on the Person type, as discussed in the convo below the question. Unfortunately I couldn't get that to work.

Comment: I answered above, but where you put it just depends. If person has another object inside it and so on, you want the rules on the custom element for that object, not the parent.